# Find a vector equation of the plane that is perpendicular to the x-axis and contains the point P(1,1,3)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this question on a sample midterm for an introductory course on linear Algebra. Even though, I solved it, I am quite unsure if the solution is correct.

Here's what I did-

1. To find vector equation of plane, we need a point on the plane and two non-collinear vectors that are parallel to the plane
2. Vector equation of the plane is given as-$$\vec{x}=\vec{x}_0+t_1 \vec{v}_1+t_2 \vec{v}_2$$
3. here, $$\vec{x}_0=(1,1,3)$$
4. So, essentially, I just have to find two more points on the plane which will help me find the other two vectors in the plane equation.
5. So, the diagram looks as follows-
   [image]

6. and hence, I can select any point changing y and z, keeping x the same(since the plane is perpendicular to x-axis)
7. From the random points , I will be able to find $$\vec{v}_1$$ and $$\vec{v}_2$$
8. and I could substitute that into equation to get the answer.

Comment: $x=1$ should do the trick.

Comment: @JohnDouma I mean the solution process is correct right? I am not very concerned about the values.

Comment: In a case like this, I believe a formal process shows a lack of understanding. If I asked for the area under the curve $y=x$ from $x=0$ to $x=1$ would you really do an integral?

Comment: Everything is correct. At step 6 I would think of two vectors originating at the given point, having the same x-coordinate and different y and z. Make sure the two vectors are not collinear (or parallel, or linearly dependent- in that case you would build the equation of a line)

Comment: @WindSoul Thanks, got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector directed along x axis is $$\vec n=(1,0,0)$$
The vector equation of the plane is
$$\vec n\cdot(\vec r-\vec r_0)=0\Leftrightarrow 1\cdot(x-1)+0\cdot(y-1)+0\cdot(z-3)=0$$

The equation of the plane perpendicular to x-axis and passing through (1,1,3) is
$$x=1$$